# Filling a custom shape with Android API Level 1 Path Calls

Tags: android, canvas, graphics, path

I am attempting to create a custom shape that needs to be filled. I cannot use the "arcTo" method and have to only use moveTo, lineTo and addArc.

Here is the code I have...

```
            bubblePaintOutline = new Paint();
            bubblePaintOutline.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            bubblePaintOutline.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
            bubblePaintOutline.setStrokeWidth(10f);

            outlinePath.moveTo(bubbleRect.left, bubbleRect.top);
            outlinePath.addArc(new RectF(bubbleRect.left, bubbleRect.top, bubbleRect.left + (2 * margin), bubbleRect.top + (2 * margin)), 180, 90f);
            outlinePath.moveTo(bubbleRect.left+(margin),bubbleRect.top);
            outlinePath.lineTo(bubbleRect.right-(margin),bubbleRect.top);
            outlinePath.addArc(new RectF(bubbleRect.right-(2*margin), bubbleRect.top,bubbleRect.right,bubbleRect.top+(2*margin)),270,90f);
            outlinePath.moveTo(bubbleRect.right,bubbleRect.top+margin);
            outlinePath.lineTo(bubbleRect.right,bubbleRect.bottom-margin);
            outlinePath.addArc(new RectF(bubbleRect.right-(2*margin), bubbleRect.bottom-(2*margin),bubbleRect.right,bubbleRect.bottom),0,90f);
            outlinePath.moveTo(bubbleRect.right-margin,bubbleRect.bottom);
            outlinePath.lineTo((3.0f/4.0f)*bubbleRect.width()+bubbleRect.left,bubbleRect.bottom);
            outlinePath.lineTo(position.x, position.y);
            outlinePath.lineTo(position.x,bubbleRect.bottom);
            outlinePath.lineTo(bubbleRect.left+margin, bubbleRect.bottom);
            outlinePath.addArc(new RectF(bubbleRect.left, bubbleRect.bottom-(2*margin),bubbleRect.left+(2*margin),bubbleRect.bottom),90,90f);
            outlinePath.moveTo(bubbleRect.left,bubbleRect.bottom-margin);
            outlinePath.lineTo(bubbleRect.left,bubbleRect.top+margin);
            outlinePath.moveTo(bubbleRect.left,bubbleRect.top);
            outlinePath.close();
```

The code successfully draws the shape I desire and fills in a small triangle, but the bulk of the shape is not filled. (The only part that is filled is between 2 "lineTo"s in a row.

How can I use addArc and still fill the shape in?

Answer (score 0):

Add calls to outlinePath.close() before you call moveTo() to close the previous section